# Setting up a property inside function and call it back after Element get

Tags: javascript

In the example below, I have a function called `color()`. Is it possible to make it work as I would expect?

```html
<div> text text </div>

<script>
function color(property) {
    return this.style.color = property;
}

document.getElementsByTagName("div").color("red"); 
</script>
```

The code above gives me the error:

```
color(...) is not a function
```

Comment: `document.getElementByTagName("div")` returns a nodelist / collection of elements. Also it should have an "S" after Element `document.getElementsByTagName("div")`

Comment: @kakashisenpai: I've rolled back your edit just now. On SO, we don't edit questions such that they invalidate existing answers, it makes for a confusing situation where the answer seems to say something the question doesn't ask (in this case, that there is no `getElementByTagName` function).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , no you get me wrong in my local .js file its getElements `with s` not getElement i just made mistake when i was typing here, its typing fault not a knowledge fault .

Comment: @kakashisenpai: I understand. But the way SO works, once it's been addressed by an answer, we don't change it in the question. But meh, it's not an important part of the answer, I'll just modify the answer. (But in general, don't do that, it's not how SO works and it can trigger quite negative reactions.) Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder > thank you sir , you are a gentleman :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems and an issue with that code:

1. `getElementsByTagName` returns a *collection* of elements, not just a single element. [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method).
2. There's nothing that attaches the function `color` to an element or collection of elements.
3. To use `this` as the element, you'll need to make sure `color` is called in a special way.

Also note there's no need for the `return` in `color`.

If you want to apply the `color` function to all matching elements, you'll need a loop:

```js
function color(property) {
    this.style.color = property;
}

var list = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
  color.call(list[i], "red"); 
}
```

```html
<div> text text </div>
```

But if you don't use `this`, the call is clearer:

```js
function color(el, property) {
    el.style.color = property;
}

var list = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
  color(list[i], "red"); 
}
```

```html
<div> text text </div>
```

---

Note: You *could* add a property to the `HTMLElement` prototype (or even `NodeList` or `HTMLCollection`) so you could call `color` as a method, as you did in your question. That's probably not a good idea; if everyone did it, it would quickly lead to conflicts. Generally it's better to only modify the built-in DOM prototypes when applying a polyfill, but not for custom functions.

Comment: thank you sir nice explain :) , i learned good stuff in your post , but why some ppl down vote my question ? its a javascript question where is the bad thing here ? we ask because we dont know , if we already know as they expect then no need to ask then . the logic in this website is broken

Comment: @kakashisenpai: FWIW, they probably felt you didn't do enough research before posting. More here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users